# How can I use wildcard character in validation-text.properties file?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make spring use my custom error message for error on fields on object in a List during form binding.

A clearer version of the above question is:

I have class looking like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private Long fooId;
    private Long number;

    //getters and setters stuff
}
```

Then a class Bar which `HAS-A` list of `Foo`s:

```
public class Bar
{
    private List<Foo> foos;

    //other stuff
}
```

*IF* my Bar only has one single `Foo`, then the following message key (in validation-text.properties) is used

```
typeMismatch.bar.foo.number=Invalid data.
```

HOWEVER, because I have a list of `Foo`s, the field is actually `foos[0].number` or `foos[1].number`, etc.

So obviously, `typeMismatch.bar.foo` wouldn't be resolved to anything.

My question is, how can I specify something like this in my validation-text.properties field:

```
typeMismatch.bar.foos[*].number=Invalid data. ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which keys you can use in validation-text.properties by inspecting `BindingResult` object. Add `BindingResult result` as a parameter to your controller method (if you don't have it there already) and then when validation error happens take a look at result.getFieldError().getCodes() (this should contain codes for the first field error if there is any).

**EDIT**

I have tried out your example and inspected the codes in `BindingResult`. Any of the following codes should work

- typeMismatch.bar.foos[1].number
- typeMismatch.bar.foos.number
- typeMismatch.foos[1].number
- typeMismatch.foos.number
- typeMismatch.number
- typeMismatch.java.lang.Long
- typeMismatch

So, to get what you wish you only need to add 's' to what you've already tried (it's foos not foo):

`typeMismatch.bar.foos.number=Invalid data.`